# Add Incremental keys to array of object

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

I need your help;

Assume I have an array of objects like this

```
{
    'Name:'ABC',
    'Code': 'BP'
}
```

Which the best way to add an incremental attribute to this array in typescript.

```
[{'Name':'ABC','Code':'BP','ID':0}, [{'Name':'ABD','Code':'DP','ID':1},…]
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What do you mean by adding an incremental attribute? The objects in the array have their respective index.

Comment: In fact it's a problem with FormArray(Angular). So  I'd like to add an integer index inside the object and that index should start from 0. this index will be used as key for the object

Comment: But why do you need it inside the object? You have the index in the FormArray itself, that should be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
arrayOfObjects.forEach((obj, index) => obj.ID = index)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to consider if you want to **mutate** or not the input.

The `forEach` approach would mutate the input which is not always recommended.

Consider this:

```js
var data = [{Name:'ABC',Code: 'BP'}]
const mutate = data.map((x, i) => (x.ID = i, x))
console.log(data)
```

A similar approach to the `forEach` in which as you can see the data got `mutated`.

Now consider a [pure approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) like this:

```js
var data = [{Name:'ABC', Code: 'BP'}]
const pure = data.map((x, i) => ({...x, ID:i}))
console.log(data, pure)
```

Note that data (the input to the function) did not change and we got the output we ware after.